# Write variable output to a specific column in a CSV?

Tags: python, excel, csv, xlrd, scrape

I'm working on a Python script that scrapes data from an Excel doc, then writes the output to a .csv.

I was able to grab the data and get it to write to the .csv, but all of the data goes into the first column.

I need the bar data to go into the 4th and the foo to go into the 5th column, so I tried to use csv.reader to select the row, and this runs without error but doesn't actually write to the .csv file.

Here's my code:

```
 import xlrd
 import csv

 ###Grab the data 
 def get_row_values(workSheet, row):
     to_return = []
     num_cells = myWorksheet.ncols - 1
     curr_cell = -1
     while curr_cell < num_cells:
         curr_cell += 1
         cell_value = myWorksheet.cell_value(row, curr_cell)
         to_return.append(cell_value)
     return to_return

 file_path = 'map_test.xlsx'
 output = []
 output_bar = []
 output_foo = []

 myWorkbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_path)
 myWorksheet = myWorkbook.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
 num_rows = myWorksheet.nrows - 1
 curr_row = 0
 column_names = get_row_values(myWorksheet, curr_row)
 print len(column_names)
 while curr_row < num_rows:
        curr_row += 1 
        row = myWorksheet.row(curr_row)
        this_row = get_row_values(myWorksheet, curr_row)
        x = 0
        while x <len(this_row):
            if this_row[x] == 'x':
                    output.append([this_row[0], column_names[x]])
                    output_bar.append([column_names[x]]) 
                    output_foo.append([this_row[0]])
                    print output
                    myData = [["number", "name", "version", "bar", 
 "foo"]]

                    ##### Next section is the code in question, it 
 ####doesn't error out, but won't write to the .csv######

                myFile = open("test123.csv", "w")
                writer = csv.writer(myFile)
                with open('test123.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
                    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
                    for row in reader:
                        row[5] = myFile.readline()
                        writer.writerows(output_foo)
                        row[4] = myFile.readline()
                        writer.writerows(outpu_bar)

                        #####This successfully writes to the csv, but      
 #####all data to first column#####

    #           myFile = open('test123.csv', 'w')
    #           with myFile:
    #                   writer = csv.writer(myFile)
    #                   writer.writerows(myData)
    #                   #writer.writerows(output)
    #                   writer.writerows(output_foo)
    #                   writer.writerows(output_bar)

            x += 1

 print ("CSV Written")
```

Comment: There is a bit of confusion in your code... but it's an old post and maybe you have solved the various issues.  At any rate, you are opening for reading and writing the same file at the same moment, and this is _bad_, further you seem to open the csv _each time!_ that you read a row in xlsx file and this is _bad_ too.  What you want, so it seems to me, is to merge data from xlsx into an existing csv, in this case you have to perform 4 tasks _in sequence_: ① read data from xlsx ② read data from csv ③ merge data ④ write data to csv.  Tell me if you can solve your issues or you need further help.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you for the post. I did already solve this problem but still learned something from your comment.